# Can't assign submit event type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Basically the title. Here is how the code looks:

```
 const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // e.preventDefault()
  }

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
```

Here is the error in full detail:

```
Type '(e: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.
      Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' provides no match for the signature '(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1380, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onSubmit' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<FormHTMLAttributes<HTMLFormElement>, HTMLFormElement>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We have to use `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` type for our form event.

```
const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    // e.preventDefault()
}

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}></form>
```

`React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>` is a handler type for handling form elements.

`React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>` leads to below function type

```
(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => void;
```

You can even give `FormEventHandler` type to your `handleSubmit` function if you want,

```
const handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement> = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
  // e.preventDefault()
};
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: Type '(e: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.
      Type 'FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>' provides no match for the signature '(event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>): void'.ts(2322)

Comment: the type of event is 'FormEvent' not 'FormEventHandler' `(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>)`

Comment: What if I need to pass in another parameter?

Comment: `onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, values)}` and `const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HtmlFormElement> , values: string[])  => { }`

Comment: @SubratoPattanaik I tried this and suddenly I "can't find the parameter 'V' "

Comment: I don't think we can do this `const handleSubmit: React.FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>` if our handleSubmit is returning `void`. I tried and it is giving error `Type '(e: FormEvent<Element>, chosenTags: string[ ]) => void' is not assignable to type 'FormEventHandler<HTMLFormElement>'.`